# Узнать значение переменной через командную строку

Tags: память, cmd, переменные, консоль

есть процесс **NFS**, есть адрес ячейки памяти **013AAE1A** с каким-то значением. Можно ли через командную строку обратиться к этому процессу и вывести значение на экран?

Comment: gdb и присоединиться к процессу. затем print (p)

Comment: gdb это отдельный редактор, как мне его связать с консолью?

Comment: В работе подключение к процессам не использовал, но простейший случай:

    sudo gdb <имя задачи> <pid>

    (gdb) p /x *<address>

т.е. p /x *0x013AAE1A

Comment: Где же мне взять этот gdb? где это писать? Я о нем вообще первый раз сейчас слышу. Объясни пожалуйста.

Comment: Если в линуксе, то gdb как правило уже установлен. Если нет, то ставится из репозитория очень просто.

Comment: винда. Как? я же сказал что первый раз имею дело с этим. И гугл отказывается помогать.

Comment: Для винды тоже хочу такое) Насколько я понял, по этому же принципу артмани работает. А это крутая штука `^,,^`

Comment: Google: "gdb windows download" Результатов: примерно 10 600 000 (0,16 сек.)

@Артем Дозоров, просто интересно, что в гугле набирали ?

Comment: по запросу "Хрень" тоже 22 миллиона результатов, только это ни хрена не дает. Вопрос не в том где это скачать, а в том что это из себя представляет и с чем его едят.

Comment: man gdb, gdb tutorial

и читать ...

Comment: @avp Учитывая, что описание gdb в формате pdf имеет объём более 500 страниц, то читать, читать и читать... (На самом деле для этой задачи надо совсем немного. Ежели, конечно, ещё и скрипт написать...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел [пример на хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/cpp/93437/), c++.

Плюс [исходник на delphi](http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/sources/system/2008-year/simple-memory-seeker.html), который можно переделать в консольный при желании.

Плюс народ намекнул на винапишные функции ([Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) OR [Write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681674%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))ProcessMemory.

Соответственно готовый консольник вы вряд ли найдете, а вот написать должно быть несложно (хотя, скорее всего не быстро).

А потом просто в батнике пишете что-то вроде

```
@echo off
start "C:\prog\showAddr.exe -NFS.exe -013AAE1A -4"
```

А в консольнике проверяете первый и второй параметры, потом ищете процесс `arg[0]` и смещение `arg[1]` длиной `arg[2]` байт в нем и выводите значение.